# Detect Desktop and redirect..?

Tags: php, redirect, mobile, desktop, browser-detection

I want to redirect all the users to 
desktop site who try to browse **mobile site** in there **desktop browsers**..!!
i'm currently using

```
<?php
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
header('Location: http://example.com/mobile');
?>
```

**To redirect the mobile users from desktop to the mobile site** 
and ya i don't wnat to use !(not equals to in above code)
like this

```
<?php
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(!preg_match('/android|avantgo|bl
```

**But just want to redirect the desktop users to desktop webiste try to browse mobile site on desktop or laptops..!!**
THANKS

Comment: You can try to use JavaScript to detect device resolution, if less than 1024x768 it's more likely to be mobile browser.

Comment: @nazaiy well i think it will best to use PHP at the top of theme file for detecting it..!!
cause the code is placed over mobile theme file..!!
and might going to load on every page can cause trouble for mobile users..!!
well in short you can you say that i just want destkop user-agent strings.!! thanks

Comment: Have you considered terawurfl? http://dbapi.scientiamobile.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: @pelshoff i really don't know about this.. let me check..!!

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to predict every possible user agent string for desktop browser, more natural and user friendly way would be JavaScript with cookie validation.

For example:

```
<?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['isMobileBrowser'])):?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    if(screen.width >= "1024" || screen.height >= "768")
    {
        //desktop
        document.cookie="isMobileBrowser=false";
        window.location.replace('http://www.example.com/');

    }
    else
    {
        //mobile
        var redirect = confirm("Switch to mobile version?");

        if(redirect)
        {
            document.cookie="isMobileBrowser=true";
            window.location.replace('http://mobile.example.com/');
        }
        else
        {
            document.cookie="isMobileBrowser=false";
        }
    }

</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This method will soon become unreliable as it's not future-proof, there are already mobile devices & smart phones that succeed 1024px.

Comment: @JulienEtienne - it depends on purpose of mobile device detection. If you are worried that page layout would not fit on screen, such approach would do the job and quite reliable (if it supports JavaScript), unless you are concern about page loading time or bandwidth consumption and willing to display simplified version of website. In this scenario you would have to go through user agent matching.

Comment: (The "if statement is not relative to the design of the site). It's saying: "if less than XGA go to mobile device".My argument isn't really that JavaScript isn't reliable, it's more that using "screen.width" or "width" via any means for mobile detection should be avoided. The best approach would be to use server side user agent detection, "I don't get why he doesn't want to use '!'".